# OpenGL copy ColorAttachment0 from a Renderbuffer to a Texture2D

Tags: c#, opengl, copy, framebuffer, texture2d

I'm using OpenTK and C#.
I'm rendering to a renderbuffer and I need to copy it's contents(ColorAttachment0) to a Texture2D so I can do some post-processing on it, and the draw it to the screen. How do I do this?
I would use texture instead of a renderbuffer, but I need to Anti-alias the framebuffer, and using GL.RenderbufferStorageMultisample is the only way I know how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create another FBO and attach the texture to it. Bind the multisampled FBO to GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER and the texture FBO to GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER. Then call [glBlitFramebuffer](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBlitFramebuffer.xml) with the correct parameters. This will copy and resolve the samples to make non-multisampled data, and output it to the texture.

If you want to resolve the samples directly, you can use the GL_ARB_texture_multisample extension.

Comment: Okay, I now it works with normal framebuffers, but I get InvalidFramebufferOperationExt when using a multisample framebuffer. Is there anything extra I need to setup for multisample framebuffers?My code: http://pastebin.com/N2ZjCVy5

Comment: @Daniel Are you sure your framebuffers are complete? Looks like your depth texture is not multisampled (it should). Change it to a RB with the same number of samples as color.

Comment: IT WORKS! (using a multisample renderbuffer for both depth and color) Thank you soo much :)